# How do I INSERT OVERWRITE with a struct in HIVE?

Tags: insert, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table **tweets** stored as text that I am trying to write to another table **tweetsORC** that is ORC. Both have the same structure:

```
col_name    data_type   comment
racist                  boolean                 from deserializer   
contributors            string                  from deserializer   
coordinates             string                  from deserializer   
created_at              string                  from deserializer   
entities                struct<hashtags:array<string>,symbols:array<string>,urls:array<struct<display_url:string,expanded_url:string,indices:array<tinyint>,url:string>>,user_mentions:array<string>>   from deserializer   
favorite_count          tinyint                 from deserializer   
favorited               boolean                 from deserializer   
filter_level            string                  from deserializer   
geo                     string                  from deserializer   
id                      bigint                  from deserializer   
id_str                  string                  from deserializer   
in_reply_to_screen_name string                  from deserializer   
in_reply_to_status_id   string                  from deserializer   
in_reply_to_status_id_str   string                  from deserializer   
in_reply_to_user_id     string                  from deserializer   
in_reply_to_user_id_str string                  from deserializer   
is_quote_status         boolean                 from deserializer   
lang                    string                  from deserializer   
place                   string                  from deserializer   
possibly_sensitive      boolean                 from deserializer   
retweet_count           tinyint                 from deserializer   
retweeted               boolean                 from deserializer   
source                  string                  from deserializer   
text                    string                  from deserializer   
timestamp_ms            string                  from deserializer   
truncated               boolean                 from deserializer   
user                    struct<contributors_enabled:boolean,created_at:string,default_profile:boolean,default_profile_image:boolean,description:string,favourites_count:tinyint,follow_request_sent:string,followers_count:tinyint,following:string,friends_count:tinyint,geo_enabled:boolean,id:bigint,id_str:string,is_translator:boolean,lang:string,listed_count:tinyint,location:string,name:string,notifications:string,profile_background_color:string,profile_background_image_url:string,profile_background_image_url_https:string,profile_background_tile:boolean,profile_image_url:string,profile_image_url_https:string,profile_link_color:string,profile_sidebar_border_color:string,profile_sidebar_fill_color:string,profile_text_color:string,profile_use_background_image:boolean,protected:boolean,screen_name:string,statuses_count:smallint,time_zone:string,url:string,utc_offset:string,verified:boolean> from deserializer
```

When I try to insert from tweets to tweetsORC I get:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tweetsORC SELECT * FROM tweets;
FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToString with (struct<hashtags:array<string>,symbols:array<string>,urls:array<struct<display_url:string,expanded_url:string,indices:array<tinyint>,url:string>>,user_mentions:array<string>>). Possible choices: _FUNC_(bigint)  _FUNC_(binary)  _FUNC_(boolean)  _FUNC_(date)  _FUNC_(decimal(38,18))  _FUNC_(double)  _FUNC_(float)  _FUNC_(int)  _FUNC_(smallint)  _FUNC_(string)  _FUNC_(timestamp)  _FUNC_(tinyint)  _FUNC_(void)
```

The only help I have found on this kind of problem says to make a UDF use primitive types, but I am not using a UDF! Any help is much appreciated!

FYI: Hive version:

Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258
Subversion git://u12-slave-5708dfcd-10/grid/0/jenkins/workspace/HDP-build-ubuntu12/bigtop/output/hive/hive-1.2.1000.2.4.2.0 -r 240760457150036e13035cbb82bcda0c65362f3a

EDIT: Create tables and sample data:

```
create table tweets (
  contributors string,
  coordinates string,
  created_at string,
  entities struct <
    hashtags: array <string>,
    symbols: array <string>,
    urls: array <struct <
        display_url: string,
        expanded_url: string,
        indices: array <tinyint>,
        url: string>>,
    user_mentions: array <string>>,
  favorite_count tinyint,
  favorited boolean,
  filter_level string,
  geo string,
  id bigint,
  id_str string,
  in_reply_to_screen_name string,
  in_reply_to_status_id string,
  in_reply_to_status_id_str string,
  in_reply_to_user_id string,
  in_reply_to_user_id_str string,
  is_quote_status boolean,
  lang string,
  place string,
  possibly_sensitive boolean,
  retweet_count tinyint,
  retweeted boolean,
  source string,
  text string,
  timestamp_ms string,
  truncated boolean,
  `user` struct <
    contributors_enabled: boolean,
    created_at: string,
    default_profile: boolean,
    default_profile_image: boolean,
    description: string,
    favourites_count: tinyint,
    follow_request_sent: string,
    followers_count: tinyint,
    `following`: string,
    friends_count: tinyint,
    geo_enabled: boolean,
    id: bigint,
    id_str: string,
    is_translator: boolean,
    lang: string,
    listed_count: tinyint,
    location: string,
    name: string,
    notifications: string,
    profile_background_color: string,
    profile_background_image_url: string,
    profile_background_image_url_https: string,
    profile_background_tile: boolean,
    profile_image_url: string,
    profile_image_url_https: string,
    profile_link_color: string,
    profile_sidebar_border_color: string,
    profile_sidebar_fill_color: string,
    profile_text_color: string,
    profile_use_background_image: boolean,
    protected: boolean,
    screen_name: string,
    statuses_count: smallint,
    time_zone: string,
    url: string,
    utc_offset: string,
    verified: boolean>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/ed/Downloads/hive-json-master/1abbo.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tweets;

create table tweetsORC (
racist boolean,
  contributors string,
  coordinates string,
  created_at string,
  entities struct <
    hashtags: array <string>,
    symbols: array <string>,
    urls: array <struct <
        display_url: string,
        expanded_url: string,
        indices: array <tinyint>,
        url: string>>,
    user_mentions: array <string>>,
  favorite_count tinyint,
  favorited boolean,
  filter_level string,
  geo string,
  id bigint,
  id_str string,
  in_reply_to_screen_name string,
  in_reply_to_status_id string,
  in_reply_to_status_id_str string,
  in_reply_to_user_id string,
  in_reply_to_user_id_str string,
  is_quote_status boolean,
  lang string,
  place string,
  possibly_sensitive boolean,
  retweet_count tinyint,
  retweeted boolean,
  source string,
  text string,
  timestamp_ms string,
  truncated boolean,
  `user` struct <
    contributors_enabled: boolean,
    created_at: string,
    default_profile: boolean,
    default_profile_image: boolean,
    description: string,
    favourites_count: tinyint,
    follow_request_sent: string,
    followers_count: tinyint,
    `following`: string,
    friends_count: tinyint,
    geo_enabled: boolean,
    id: bigint,
    id_str: string,
    is_translator: boolean,
    lang: string,
    listed_count: tinyint,
    location: string,
    name: string,
    notifications: string,
    profile_background_color: string,
    profile_background_image_url: string,
    profile_background_image_url_https: string,
    profile_background_tile: boolean,
    profile_image_url: string,
    profile_image_url_https: string,
    profile_link_color: string,
    profile_sidebar_border_color: string,
    profile_sidebar_fill_color: string,
    profile_text_color: string,
    profile_use_background_image: boolean,
    protected: boolean,
    screen_name: string,
    statuses_count: smallint,
    time_zone: string,
    url: string,
    utc_offset: string,
    verified: boolean>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

data [here](http://dropcanvas.com/7b4wd).

Comment: could you provide the create tables and some data sample to replicate the problem?

Comment: Hi lake. I'm away but I will try and edit it tonight.

Comment: Done! And thanks for looking.

Comment: There is an enormous amount of unnecessary code/data here. See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No there isn't. It's just what was requested.

Comment: @schoon yes there is.  The error is very specific.  It is having a problem creating the column `entities`.  Every other column in this code is unnecessary to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Select * I list the fields by name and the error goes.

Answer (score 0):

Data type mismatch: The data type you want to insert is inconsistent with the field type in the corresponding data table. For example, if the field type declared when you create the table is string, but the field type you inserted is indeed the list type, this error will be thrown.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?